# The program won't read the second vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

So I tried to write a function that can return the scalar product of two vectors (i.e. a0b0 + a1b1 + ...), but whenever I run the program, it would only read in the first set of input (i.e. vector a), and after that the second vector (vector b) is automatically "skipped" and the program returns a very strange number like 2.122e-314. So what's the problem in this code? (For simplicity, I just assumed that vectors a and b have the same size.) Thx!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/**
 Calculates the scalar product of two vectors.
 @param a, b two vectors
 @return the sum of product of two vectors: a0b0 + a1b1 + ...
 */
double scalar_product (vector<double>& a, vector<double>& b)
{
    double product;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        product += a[i] * b[i];
    return product;
}

/**
 Reads in a new vector.
 */
vector<double> read (vector<double>& a)
{
    bool more = true;
    while (more)
    {
        double s;
        cin >> s;
        if (cin.fail())
            more = false;
        else
            a.push_back(s);
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> a;
    cout << "Please enter the numbers of the first series, enter any non-number character to quit: ";
    read (a);

    vector<double> b;
    cout << "Please enter the numbers of the second series, enter any non-number character to quit: ";
    read (b);
    cout << "The scalar product of the two series is " << scalar_product(a, b) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `cin.clear()` after reading your first vector to reset the error flags.  As mentioned by Peter, you also need to ignore the non-number characters from `cin`.  You can do this with something like `cin.ignore(10000,'\n');`, which will ignore all of the characters until a new line.

Comment: and probably you need to remove, i.e. read the pending non number input from cin before you attempt to read more numbers.

Comment: So I added "cin.clear()" after "more = false", now it asks for my input on the second series; however, when I input a number "e.g. 2", it tells me "error: 2 is not a valid command". Why is that?

Comment: JupiterM: See the revision to my answer about `cin.ignore`

Comment: GWW: Thx, that cin.ignore worked. Now it works as I expected, so as far as I have tried. Thanks.

Comment: My general advice is to avoid manual input and prepare files which you connect to the standard input of your program with "prog < file" which should work at a windows command prompt and in unix shells. It's less tiresome, gives you better reproducability and avoids messy newlines and other funny artifacts from keyboard input. Then you'll need some assumption about the vector sizes, or you have the element count as the first number, or you read all numbers in a start vector till eof and then split that in two.

Comment: I did intend to use input redirection, but I'm using Xcode cuz I'm on a Mac, and Xcode has a weird directory of file input, so I used keyboard instead.

Comment: @GWW One more question, should I put 'cin.clear()' before or after 'cin.ignore()'?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to clear the error state and flush the input buffer. It won't magically just happen.
- `scalar_product()` exhibits **undefined behavior** if the second vector is smaller than the first one.
  Anyway, the mathematical scalar product is only defined for two equal sized vectors.

Comment: I originally wrote a code for cases where two vectors are not the same size, but I haven't checked whether that will work yet, so for the sake of simplicity, I changed them to a simpler version here.

Comment: Just 0-padding the smaller vector (same as truncating the larger one) should work.

Comment: So does that mean ignoring the elements after the index of the last element of the smaller one to make them the same size?

Comment: Ok, I see. Sorry, I didn't know the mathematical definition of scalar product, so I assumed adding the elements in the larger vector only after exceeding the index of the smaller one. But now that I checked how scalar product really works, this makes perfect sense. Thanks.